# Laravel Eloquent returns empty model even though ID is correct

Tags: laravel, model, routes, eloquent, parameter-passing

so I have an Axios get request to this route:

```
/threads/test/{fooId}/get
```

which is handled by this method:

```
public function apiThreadsByTag(Foo $foo)
{
    dd($foo);
}
```

Foo is a model, and the {id} is indeed correct. But still, I get an instance of the model without any attributes:

```
Foo {#323
    #guarded: []
    #connection: null
    #table: null
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #keyType: "int"
    +incrementing: true
    #with: []
    #perPage: 15
    +exists: false
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    #attributes: []
    #original: []
    #casts: []
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #appends: []
    #events: []
    #observables: []
    #relations: []
    #touches: []
    +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
}
```

However, it does find it in the database if I change the method to:

```
public function apiThreadsByTag($fooId)
{
    dd(Foo::find($fooId));
}
```

So, what could be wrong here? I'm very thankful for any hints!

Comment: try to change the name of the var, make it same as wildcard. like so :public function apiThreadsByTag(Foo $fooId)
{
    dd($fooId);
}

Comment: Did you apply the correct route model binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did everything correct. Well, except for the fact that I set getRouteKeyName() for the Foo model to another value and not the ID. So I had to give it this set value instead of the ID. Thank you!